# Регулярное выражение для preg_split

Tags: php

Имеется строка вида

`{option:string} {value:numeric}`

Нуно ее переобразить в массив вида:

```
[
    'option','string'
    'value', 'numeric'
]
```

Пробую вот таким макаром:

```
preg_split("/[{.*:.*}]/", "{option:string} {value:numeric}");
```

Но получаю массив вида:

```
  0 => ""
  1 => "option"
  2 => "string"
  3 => " "
  4 => "value"
  5 => "numeric"
  6 => ""
```

Какое добавить правило для пробелов, чтоб убрать пустые строки?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_split("/[{: }]/", "{option:string} {value:numeric} {option:string} {value:numeric}",-1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

```
Array ( [0] => option [1] => string [2] => value [3] => numeric [4] => option [5] => string [6] => value [7] => numeric )
```